# got attribute error after executing the KNN imputation

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, fancyimpute

this is the code

```
sales = pd.DataFrame(KNN(k = 3).complete(sales), columns = sales.columns)
```

**and i recieved this error :**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f9b501774a0e> in <module>
      1 #Impute with KNN
----> 2 sales = pd.DataFrame(KNN(k = 3).complete(sales), columns = sales.columns)

AttributeError: 'KNN' object has no attribute 'complete'
```

**then i used this:**

```
sales = pd.DataFrame(KNN(k = 3).fit_transform(sales), columns = sales.columns)
```

**but got this error instead**

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2/24/2003 0:00'
```

Comment: Your data contains columns with datetime format. TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, datetime is not accept.

Comment: @whoisraibolt as i a new to programming i dont understand much about it can you please explain it